# Android: On-click not working with textview with wrap_content and imageview

Tags: android, listview

I cannot get  the on-click listener to work correctly in my listview.

I have a listview with complex rows containing textviews, on-click listeners, and a picture.  Most times, the picture forces the row to be at least 3 lines high.

Example Row:

```
textView  textView  imageView
+--------+---------+------------+
|tvAge   |tvName   |ivPicture   |
|        |         |That causes |
|        |         |3 lines     |
+--------+---------+------------+
             |
         Cannot Click
```

If the text-view "tvName" is set to fill_parent, and the text needs to wrap, it does not wrap the text when there is no picture to expand the row, but instead only displays the first line of data.

If the text-view "tvName" is set to wrap-content, it will display all the data, wrapping it with or without the picture, but you CANNOT tap on the white space below it to fire the on-click listener.

Code snippet:

The row is actually much more complex, and the "llQuantity" LinearLayout is required for other reasons.

```
tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  { public void onClick(View v) { Log.w("CK", "we are clicked" ); return; }});

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llQuantity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAge"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/file_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try android:layout_width="0dp" for tvName.

Answer (score 0):

try this once then tell me if work will give you proper solution

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/llQuantity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAge"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:toLeftOf="@+id/ivImage"
        android:toRightOf="@+id/tvAge"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/file_icon" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

to TextView.

For example:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvAge"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
```

Hope this helps.